# Heroku trusted proxies

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm running a **symfony2** application on **Heroku**, and I need to get the **trusted proxies**  ( IP(s) )
behind which my app is going to be running as described in here : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-use-sub-networks-to-configure-trusted-proxies

There is a mention about the IP(s) a Dyno can get in the [Dyno manifold](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ip-addresses)  that say :

> When running multiple dynos, apps are distributed across several nodes
>   by the dyno manager. Access to your app always goes through the
>   routers.
>
> As a result, dynos don’t have static IP addresses. While you can never
>   connect to a dyno directly, it is possible to originate outgoing
>   requests from a dyno. However, you can count on the dyno’s IP address
>   changing as it gets restarted in different places.

The framework actually has some option like :

```
framework:
    trust_proxy_headers: true
```

But this is going to be deprecated soon...

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably just add a call in your front controller that trusts the incoming IP (since the only way to get to your server is via the Heroku routing layer):

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

Comment: That is indeed true, but I'm not sure if there is a hole in this, I need to investigate !
Thanks !

Comment: I think it's the right answer as heroku will set REMOTE_ADDR in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these [Heroku instructions for Symfony](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony#trusting-the-load-balancer) and the [Heroku headers list](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers), we can see that the only forwarded headers that Symfony uses and can be trusted from Heroku are `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Port`. Other headers are not to be trusted.

I would recommend the following:

```
$trustedHeaders = [
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR,
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO,
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT,
];
Request::setTrustedProxies(
    array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
    array_reduce($trustedHeaders, function($carry, $value) {
        return $carry ^ $value;
    }, 0)
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Hm, on Heroku the app running on dynos is only accessible through the routing layer/proxy so you should be fine trusting everything. Also, the IPs of the routers that proxy requests to your app are not known.

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(array('0.0.0.0/0'));
```

Comment: This will allow any request to spoof its own IP address, because you'll trust any length chain

Comment: In fact this answer is not so bad. The accepted answer will also consider any REMOTE_ADDR as trusted. In any case this is not a problem because every single request will only come from heroku.