# Symfony2: getScheme does not return 'https'

Tags: symfony, https, reverse-proxy

From within a controller, I have been using the method getSchemeAndHttpHost in order to build the url of another controller.

Everything has been running smoothly, until I needed to go over https. All urls that I get with the getSchemeAndHttpHost function are still http. Doing some troubleshooting, it came out that the getScheme function always returns http, both when I request the page with https and with http.

Did I miss something ?

How can I know if I am over http or https from my controller ?

**Edit - some more information**

1. I made sure to run the tests with a valid certificate.
2. If I run the isSecure method in my Request object, I always get false.

Comment: Well if you've got http, it means that the `isSecure()` method of the Request srevice returns false, can you test ? `$request->isSecure()`.

Comment: isSecure returns... False. I moved away from my invalid certificate, and with a valid certificate I still get $request->isSecure() to return false. I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

Add the following line in the controller:

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(array($request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));
```

**Some more details**

After some investigations, I discovered that this has to do with Proxies...
If we check what the isSecure function is doing, we find [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1158): the **Request** method **isFromTrustedProxy** is called to decide if true or false should be returned.

Once we know the issue has to do with proxies, the symfony documentation explains in details [what we should do to trust proxies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html) or [how to manage a load balancer or a reverse proxy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html). In my case, as I am working with heroku, [trusting the incoming ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180486/heroku-trusted-proxies) was the way to go.