# Laravel not using https for assets and dynamic routes

Tags: php, laravel, http, https

I've changed my APP_URL=https://example.com, I've added this into my AppServiceProvider's boot method:

```
/** Enable HTTPS */
if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS')) {
    $url->forceSchema('https');
}
```

And I've run `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`.  I still can't get assets and dynamic routes to use https.  Just getting the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://example.com/css/app.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I know I can use `secure_asset` instead of `asset` and that should work, but I need this to be dynamic, as I still need to serve the http version of the site for now on another domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `asset()` helper relies on a couple possibilities to determine whether to make a HTTP or HTTPS URL:

- `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` being `on`. This is Apache's way of doing things. For nginx, you can set that server param yourself in the config.
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` being `https`.

If you're behind a load balancer, it's probably sending the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, but Laravel doesn't trust it by default because it can be set by a malicious user in some cases. You can tell Laravel to trust this header coming from your load balancer using [the TrustedProxy package](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy). (edit: This is now [built into Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies))

See also: [Symfony2: getScheme does not return 'https'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436177/symfony2-getscheme-does-not-return-https) (Laravel uses Symfony's `getScheme()` function for this)

Comment: Thank you! Used this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Comment: @RyanBobrowski Oh sweet, I didn't know it'd been pulled into L5.

Answer (score 1):

in .env file please change the value local to production

```
APP_ENV=production
```

Comment: Keep it Simple and Silly, thank you